# Logging Artifacts from MlFlow on GCS Bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, mlflow

I have a running MlFlow server on GCS VM instance. I have created a bucket to log the artifacts.
This is the command I'm running to start the server and for specifying bucket path-

```
mlflow server --default-artifact-root gs://gcs_bucket/artifacts --host x.x.x.x
```

But facing this error:

```
TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not ElasticNet
```

Note- The mlflow server is running fine with the specified host alone. The problem is in the way when I'm specifying the storage bucket path.
I have given permission of storage api by using these commands:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
gcloud auth login
```

Also, on printing the artifact URI, this is what I'm getting:

```
mlflow.get_artifact_uri()
```

Output:

```
gs://gcs_bucket/artifacts/0/122481bf990xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/artifacts
```

So in the above path from where this is coming `0/122481bf990xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/artifacts` and why it's not getting auto-created at `gs://gcs_bucket/artifacts`

After debugging more, why it's not able to get the local path from VM:
[image]

And this error I'm getting on VM:

```
ARNING:root:Malformed experiment 'mlruns'. Detailed error Yaml file './mlruns/mlruns/meta.yaml' does not exist.
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mlflow/store/tracking/file_store.py", line 197, in list_experiments
   experiment = self._get_experiment(exp_id, view_type)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mlflow/store/tracking/file_store.py", line 256, in _get_experiment
   meta = read_yaml(experiment_dir, FileStore.META_DATA_FILE_NAME)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mlflow/utils/file_utils.py", line 160, in read_yaml
   raise MissingConfigException("Yaml file '%s' does not exist." % file_path)
mlflow.exceptions.MissingConfigException: Yaml file './mlruns/mlruns/meta.yaml' does not exist.
```

Can I get a solution to this and what I'm missing?

Comment: Have a look at https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html#google-cloud-storage .  Probably something wrong with permissions. Try to follow instructions from documentation and update your question with details.

Comment: Have you given permissions to the account that is running this command? if not, try adding the `Storage Object Viewer` and `Storage Object Creator` to check if it works.

Comment: I have updated the question, please review and try answering @SerhiiRohoza

Comment: I have given these permissions already @ralemos

Comment: Those permissions should be sufficient to allow what you are trying to do, can you try changing to the `Storage Admin` role so we can check the permissions? Also, can you try doing something like creating the object from the instance with the service account like [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-code-sample)?

Comment: I have given admin access also and tried, it's not able to log artifacts even on GCP VM instance. Check this issue- https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/2571 @ralemos

Comment: In that case, I think there might be something wrong in your VM configuration, cause on GCS everything seems to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main error is from the structure that you want to deploy. For your use case, the structure is suitable that in [here](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html#scenario-4-mlflow-with-remote-tracking-server-backend-and-artifact-stores). So you miss the URI path which used to store backend metadata. So please install DB SQL(PostgreSQL,...) first, then add the path to --backend-storage-uri.

In case you want to use MlFlow as a model registry and store images on gcs. You can use this structure in [here](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html#scenario-6-mlflow-tracking-server-used-exclusively-as-proxied-access-host-for-artifact-storage-access) with adding tag `--artifacts-only` `--serve-artifacts`

Hope this can help you.